# Ruby Sockets and parallel event handling

Tags: ruby, multithreading, events

I'm writing a library that can interact with a socket server that transmits data as events to certain actions my library sends it.

I created an Actions module that formats the actions so that the server can read it. It also generates an action_id, because the events parser can identify it with the action that sent it. There are more than one event per action possible.

While I'm sending my action to the server, the event parser is still getting data from the server, so they work independent from each other (but then again they do work together: events response aggregator triggers the action callback).

In my model, I want to get a list of some resource from the server. The server sends its data one line at a time, but that's being handled by the events aggregator, so don't worry about that.

Okay, my problem:
In my model I am requesting the resources, but since the events are being parsed in another thread, I need to do a "infinite" loop that checks if the list is filled, and then break out to return it to the consumer of the model (e.g. my controller).

Is there another (better) way of doing this or am I on the right track? I would love your thoughts :)

Here is my story in code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8652934

Answer (score 0):

#### Check out [Ruby EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/).

It's designed to simplify this sort of [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation. In the code you provide you're not showing how actually the request and responses are processed.

If you know exactly the number of responses you're supposed to receive, in each one you could check if all are completed, then execute an specific action. e.g.

```
# suppose response_receiver is the method which receives the server response
def response_receiver data
  @responses_list << data
  if @response_list.size == @expected_size
    # Execute some action
  end
end
```